# How do I convert a LPWSTR to a GUID?

Tags: c++, string, windows-7, guid

I'm working with the Windows 7 audio APIs, and I've hit a wall.

Basically, I need to take an [IAudioSessionControl2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd368248(VS.85).aspx)* and get an [ISimpleAudioVolume](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd316531(VS.85).aspx)* out of it.

Now, it looks like I can call on [IAudioSessionManager->GetSimpleAudioVolume()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd370967(VS.85).aspx) using the value of [IAudioSessionControl2->GetSessionInstanceIdentifier(...)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd368255(VS.85).aspx).  Note that this isn't exactly spelled out as such in the docs, but it seems like a reasonable behavior.

The problem, GetSimpleAudioVolume() takes a GUID* and GetSessionInstanceIdentifier() spits out a LPWSTR.  Through debugging I've confirmed that the return'd value from GetSessionInstanceIdentifier() at least *looks* like a GUID.

So, the actual question is how would I convert the LPWSTR I've got into a GUID?  I realise this is pretty trivial if I marshal across into some managed code and use built-in [GUID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/96ff78dc.aspx), but there's got to be a C++ way of doing this.

---

Ok, these APIs definitely do not work the way I say they do in the above text dump.  However, the basic question of String -> GUID is answered so I'm not going to delete the question.

Comment: Kevin, IAudioSessionManger->GetSimpleAudioVolume doesn't take a session ID.  Please, PLEASE don't attempt to treat the session identifier (or instance identifier) as anything other than an opaque string.  The format of the session identifier is subject to change at any time (for instance there were suble changes in the ID string between Vista and Win7).

Comment: Yeah, it quickly became apparent that I was "doing it wrong".

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try [`CLSIDFromString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680589(v=vs.85).aspx). A `CLSID` is actually defined as:

```
typedef GUID CLSID;
```

therefore you can use `CLSIDFromString` to generate a GUID. Here's some sample code:

```
LPWSTR guidstr;
GUID guid;

...

HRESULT hr = CLSIDFromString(guidstr, (LPCLSID)&guid);
if (hr != S_OK) {
    // bad GUID string...
    ...
}
```

### Warning

Things that are not GUIDs will return as valid GUIDs. For example:

```
| String              | Returned Clsid                         |
|---------------------|----------------------------------------|
| "file"              | {00000303-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} | FileMoniker
| "AccessControlList" | {b85ea052-9bdd-11d0-852c-00c04fd8d503} |
| "ADODB.Record"      | {00000560-0000-0010-8000-00AA006D2EA4} |
| "m"                 | {4ED063C9-4A0B-4B44-A9DC-23AFF424A0D3} | Toolbar.MySearchDial
```

This means that in addition to returning results you do not expect, the function hits the registry every time it is run.

Short version: Do not use CLSIDFromString. Instead you can use [`IIDFromString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687262(v=vs.85).aspx) in the exact same way.

Comment: You should note that this doesn't necessarily work. The relation between CLSIDs and GUIDs, although they are syntactically the same, is not a bijection. Not every GUID is also a (valid) CLSID. The function may thus fail on non-CLSID GUIDs.

Comment: @Tom Can you think of any GUID (`{xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx}`) that will fail to parse as a valid CLSID according to `CLSIDFromString`?

Comment: @Tom **Every** `GUID` (with the exception of a [`NULLGUID`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-drsr/61ffe2b7-006f-4bde-af6c-c3ecb8998eb9), maybe) is a valid `CLSID`. There's literally nothing that could conceivably fail `CLSIDFromString` on a valid `GUID` string, even if that string doesn't represent a *known* `CLSID`. `GUID`s, `CLSID`s, and `IID`s are the same thing, that just happen to mean different things in different namespaces.

Answer (score -2):

CLSIDFromString documents now point you to StringFromGUID2(), which is easier to use... and doesn't think the thing is a CLSID.