# GUID constants in C++ (in specific Orwell Dev-C++)

Tags: c++, guid

I am translating a lot of plugins from Delphi into C++, and each plugin is identified by a GUID.

In Delphi, this constant looks very nice:

```
const
  GUID_PLUGIN_ABC_V1: TGUID = '{6C26245E-F79A-416C-8C73-BEA3EC18BB6E}';
```

In my C++ translation, I would need to do following:

```
static const GUID GUID_PLUGIN_ABC_V1 =
  {0x6C26245E, 0xF79A, 0x416C, { 0x8C, 0x73, 0xBE, 0xA3, 0xEC, 0x18, 0xBB, 0x6E} };
```

This is annoying because of 2 things:

1. It is hard for me to translate, because I need to split my GUIDs by hand, and there is a risk that I do mistakes (and therefore provide a wrong GUID).
2. Since the source is public, I do want that people use the human-readable GUID, e.g. to use it for research on the web etc.
   So I would need to add a comment above the constant:

   ```
   // {6C26245E-F79A-416C-8C73-BEA3EC18BB6E}
   static const GUID GUID_PLUGIN_ABC_V1 =
     {0x6C26245E, 0xF79A, 0x416C, { 0x8C, 0x73, 0xBE, 0xA3, 0xEC, 0x18, 0xBB, 0x6E} };
   ```

Now I have following questions:

1. Is there a good **converter** for this task (for existing GUIDs)?
2. Is there a tool that can **create** new GUIDs in this constant notation?
3. Is there a possibility that I can use a Macro, like

   ```
   static const GUID GUID_PLUGIN_ABC_V1 =
     GUIDMACRO('{6C26245E-F79A-416C-8C73-BEA3EC18BB6E}')
   ```

   ?

The GUIDs are not in relation with COM.

Comment: Look at this SO post, it looks like it has the answer you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1128188/how-do-i-convert-a-lpwstr-to-a-guid

Comment: @DavidHaim This comment is absolutely unnecessary and not helpful. In VC++, the problem would be the same. And about Dev-C++ : It is a nice tool for small projects, especially plugins, which are only 1 small DLL file. And in comparison to VC++, Dev-C++ always runs&compiles out-of-the-box (thanks to the MinGW GCC compiler).

Comment: @YePhIcK Although this function works on my computer (Win10), Microsoft states that this is for CLSIDs, but my GUIDs are not related to COM, thus not registered. The method might fail. The function which would help would be GUIDFromString, but Microsoft deprecated it for some reasons.

Comment: Converting code from the Delphi format to the new C++ format can be accomplished with a basic, albeit long, regular expression find and replace.  Let me see if I can create it and post as an answer.

Answer (score 3):

You may use user defined literals:

```
#include <array>
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>

struct Guid
{
    uint32_t a = 0;
    uint16_t b = 0;
    uint16_t c = 0;
    uint16_t d = 0;
    std::array<uint8_t, 6> e;
};

Guid operator "" _guid (const char* s, std::size_t n)
{
    if(n == 38)
    {
        // Parse and consider byte order (endian).              
        // Provide something reasonable to replace this:
        if(std::strncmp(s, "{6C26245E-F79A-416C-8C73-BEA3EC18BB6E}", 36) == 0)
        {
            Guid result;
            result.a = 0x6C26245E;
            result.b = 0xF79A;
            result.c = 0x416C;
            result.d = 0x8C73;
            result.e = { 0xBE, 0xA3, 0xEC, 0x18, 0xBB, 0x6E };
            return result;
        }
    }
    // Invalid
    return Guid();
}

int main()
{
    Guid guid = "{6C26245E-F79A-416C-8C73-BEA3EC18BB6E}"_guid;
    std::cout << std::hex
        << guid.a << "-"
        << guid.b << "-"
        << guid.c << "-"
        << guid.d << "-"
        << "array\n";
}
```

See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/user_literal

Edit: Parsing

```
#include <array>
#include <cctype>
#include <cstdint>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>

#pragma pack(push, 0)
struct Guid
{
  std::uint32_t data1;
  std::uint16_t data2;
  std::uint16_t data3;
  std::array<uint8_t, 8> data4;
};
#pragma pack(pop)

// A guid with the format "01234567-89ab-cdef-0123-456789abcdef"
// If the guid string is invalid the resulting guid is an empty guid.
// Note: The first three fields of the guid are stored in a host byte order.
//       and the last two fields are stored in a single array (big endian)
Guid operator "" _guid (const char* s, std::size_t n)
{
    // Hexadecimal character test.
    struct IsXDigit
    {
        bool result = true;
        IsXDigit(const char*& p, unsigned n)
        {
            while(n--) {
                char c =  *p++;
                // char may be signed or unsigned
                if(c < 0 || 128 <= c || ! std::isxdigit(c)) {
                    result = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        operator bool () const { return result; }
    };

    Guid result;

    // Syntax
    const char* p = s;
    if( ! IsXDigit(p,  8)) goto Failure;
    if(*p++ != '-') goto Failure;
    if( ! IsXDigit(p,  4)) goto Failure;
    if(*p++ != '-') goto Failure;
    if( ! IsXDigit(p,  4)) goto Failure;
    if(*p++ != '-') goto Failure;
    if( ! IsXDigit(p,  4)) goto Failure;
    if(*p++ != '-') goto Failure;
    if( ! IsXDigit(p, 12)) goto Failure;
    if(*p)  goto Failure;

    // Data
    result.data1 = std::uint32_t(std::strtoul(s, nullptr, 16));
    result.data2 = std::uint16_t(std::strtoul(s + 9, nullptr, 16));
    result.data3 = std::uint16_t(std::strtoul(s + 14, nullptr, 16));
    char buffer[3];
    buffer[2] = 0;
    for(unsigned dst = 0, src = 19; src < 23; ++dst, src += 2)
    {
        buffer[0] = s[src];
        buffer[1] = s[src + 1];
        result.data4[dst] =  std::uint8_t(std::strtoul(buffer, nullptr, 16));
    }
    for(unsigned dst = 2, src = 24; src < 36; ++dst, src += 2)
    {
        buffer[0] = s[src];
        buffer[1] = s[src + 1];
        result.data4[dst] =  std::uint8_t(std::strtoul(buffer, nullptr, 16));
    }
    return result;

    Failure:
    std::memset(&result, 0, sizeof(result));
    return result;
}


#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main()
{
    const Guid guid = "6C26245E-F79A-416C-8C73-BEA3EC18BB6E"_guid;
    std::cout.fill('0');
    std::cout
        << std::hex
        << "6C26245E-F79A-416C-8C73-BEA3EC18BB6E\n"
        << std::setw(8) << guid.data1 << "-"
        << std::setw(4) << guid.data2 << "-"
        << std::setw(4) << guid.data3 << "-";
    for(unsigned i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
        std::cout << std::setw(2) << unsigned(guid.data4[i]);
    std::cout << "-";
    for(unsigned i = 2; i < 8; ++i)
        std::cout << std::setw(2) << unsigned(guid.data4[i]);
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Comment: I don't quite understand what the operator `_guid` does. The GUID which I want to convert , is already written in this method. So the GUID is in the code 3 times, 2 times as string and 1 time as splitted struct (which I want to avoid). So, this method converts something, that is already converted hardcoded?

Comment: The code allows you to copy and paste Delphi-Guids , however you have to replace ' by " and append _guid

Comment: The actual problem is that I don't want to manually write things like `result.a = 0x6C26245E;` by hand.

Comment: @rinntech you have to parse the string, I omitted that in the example above

Comment: I tried to use your function for the actual datatype GUID (defined in guiddef.h of the WinAPI), which is defined this way: http://pastebin.com/vwYJYZBQ . So I changed the signature to `GUID operator "" _guid (const char* s, std::size_t n)` , but I get the compiler error **[Error] no match for 'operator=' (operand types are 'GUID {aka _GUID}' and 'const char [39]')**

Answer (score 0):

Since your just transposing from text to text in a different format, Regex find and replace will work great for this.  The following was developed and tested in Notepad++.  Different editors (like Visual Studio) may have different regex rules, but the basics will be the same.

Search for:

```
const ([\w]+)\: TGUID = '\{(.{8})-(.{4})-(.{4})-(..)(..)-(..)(..)(..)(..)(..)(..)\}';
```

Replace with:

```
static const GUID $1 = {0x$2, 0x$3, 0x$4, { 0x$5, 0x$6, 0x$7, 0x$8, 0x$9, 0x$10, 0x$11, 0x$12} };
```

I can't explain all the details about using regex searches, but the basic thing to understand is that parenthesis in the search string "capture" a matched area of the line, and in the replace string $1, $2, etc insert what was captured.

For instance, the first set of parenthesis is `([\w]+)`.  This is used to capture the name of the GUID (`GUID_PLUGIN_ABC_V1` in your example).  To break it down, `[\w]` says "Match all word characters" and the `+` means "Match one or more of the preceeding character".  The parenthesis capture it , and $1 adds the name to the replace string.  The group `(.{8})` is "Match any character 8 times" and `(..)` is a pig nose...  But seriously, the `.` means "Any character", so `(..)` just matches two characters.

Note that this regex find and replace option assumes that all your incoming GUID strings are valid and follow the form of:

```
const <GUID NAME>: TGUID = '{<GUID STRING>}';
```

If there is any variation, slight changes to the regex can account for them.  Worst case is that you have a few different search and replace strings based on your various GUID formats.